# Core Data and threading

Tags: cocoa, core-data, macos

What are some of the obscure pitfalls of using Core Data and threads? I've read much of the documentation, and so far I've come across the following either in the docs or through painful experience:

- Use a new NSManagedObjectContext for each thread, but a single NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is enough for the whole app.
- Before sending an NSManagedObject's objectID back to the main thread (or any other thread), be sure the context has been saved (or at a minimum, it wasn't a newly-inserted-but-not-yet-saved object) - otherwise the objectID will actually be a temporary ID and not a persistent one.
- Use mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: to detect when a save happens in another thread and use that to merge those changes with the current thread's context.

Bonus question/observation: I was led to believe by the wording of some of the docs that mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification: is something only needed by the main thread to merge changes into the "main" context from worker threads - but I don't think that's the case.

I set up my importer to create batches of data which are imported using a subclass of an NSOperation that owns it's own context. The operations are loaded into an NSOperationQueue that's set to allow the default number of concurrent operations, so it's possible for several import batches to be running at the same time. I would occasionally get very strange validation errors and exceptions (like trying to add nil to a relationship) and other failures that I had never seen when I did all the same stuff on the main thread. It occurred to me (and perhaps this should have been obvious) that maybe the context merging needed to be done for all contexts in every thread - not just the "main" one! I don't know why I didn't think of that before, but I *think* this helped. (It hasn't been tested well enough yet for me to feel sure, though.) In any case, is it true that you need to observe that notification for ALL import threads that may be working with the same datasets and adding/updating the same entities? If so, this is yet another pitfall bullet point, IMO, although I have yet to be certain that it'll work.

Given how many of these I've run into with Core Data in general (and not all of them just about multi-threading), I have to wonder how many more are lurking. Since multi-threading so often ends up with bugs that are difficult if not impossible to reproduce due to the timing issues, I figured I'd ask if anyone had other important things that I may be missing that I need to concern myself with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an entire rather large bit of documentation devoted to the subject of [Core Data and Threading](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMultiThreading.html).

It isn't clear from your set of issues what isn't covered by that documentation.

Comment: Well that's good to hear. I have read over those docs often; each time I read them, I find new little details that I missed. The Core Data docs are very dense and often have little things like "oh, and note that <blah blah blah>" which inevitably turns out to be far more important than the "oh btw in case you were curious..." that the wording often implies (to me, anyway). Although I imagine if the entire document was bolded and set in italics, it wouldn't help much, either... :)